# Slack api and request to external service with @FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, slack-api, spring-cloud-feign, slack-bolt

I have Spring Boot with Kotlin app which uses Bolt (slack api for Java). I need to fetch data from external resource during `AppHomeOpenedEvent`. I would like to use `FeignClient` but problem is that during there is no external resource call and during debugging nothing happens (even if I try to call some random fake api found on the internet). With `RestTemplate` everything works fine. Is there any limitation with usage of slack api and openfeign?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there was a problem with configuration

```
@Configuration
class SlackAppConfig {

    @Bean
    fun slackApp(appConfig: AppConfig): App {
        return App(appConfig)
    }

    @Bean
    fun slackAppServer(app: App): SlackAppServer {
        val server = SlackAppServer(app)
        server.start()
        return server
    }
}
```

Looks like `SlackAppServer` somehow causes that FeignClient cannot be used. After changing config to

```
@Configuration
class SlackAppConfig {

    @Bean
    fun loadOAuthConfig(): AppConfig {
        return AppConfig.builder()
            //some config
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun slackApp(appConfig: AppConfig): App {
        return App(appConfig)
    }
}
```

started working